# Why do some transfers between safe wallets end with a GS026 error?

Tags: gnosis-safe, safe-core

In our application, we often order ECR20 token transactions between safe wallets (in this case from one so-called Hot Wallet to another) on the Base network.

There are times when some transactions end with a **GS026** error.

First one with success: https://basescan.org/tx/0x34190b0c29a84caeebdf704d0643b2229d287d7146a909db7afa798360d0887f

and immediatelly after https://basescan.org/tx/0xc1b83c9de94b44a1ccf37d3473406a6fd8d0ddfa5d67f3dc6e972afbd8b419e5

[image]

I noticed that they have the same block number, and only the first one was successful. However, the error also occurred for a single transaction over the longer term:

https://basescan.org/tx/0xdf10b985a893d80b67820f27d7769f4de66217896f91d5c56832936a7ceb3e2c

All transfers can be viewed here: https://basescan.org/address/0x7adc19694782c61132bcc38accaf1156d13c80d1

When several transfers (from Hot Wallet) are pending we group them and send them via MultiSend (max 10). Below is a small code, that we use to exec transaction (safe-eth-py==5.6.0):

```py
    def _create_multi_transfer(
        self, from_address: str, transfers: List[Dict[str, Union[str, str, Decimal]]]
    ) -> Tuple[str, int]:
        contract = get_erc20_contract(self.w3, self.CONTRACT_ADDRESS)

        transactions = []
        for transfer in transfers:
            tx_opts = {'from': transfer['from_address']}
            amount = self.w3.to_wei(transfer['amount'], 'ether')
            tx = contract.functions.transfer(transfer['to_address'], amount).build_transaction(tx_opts)

            ms_tx = MultiSendTx(operation=MultiSendOperation.CALL, value=0, to=self.CONTRACT_ADDRESS, data=tx['data'])
            transactions.append(ms_tx)

        multi_send = MultiSend(self.client)
        data = multi_send.build_tx_data(transactions)
        safe_tx = SafeTx(
            ethereum_client=self.client,
            safe_address=from_address,
            to=multi_send.get_contract().address,
            value=0,
            data=data,
            operation=SafeOperation.DELEGATE_CALL.value,
            safe_tx_gas=1,
            base_gas=0,
            gas_price=0,
            gas_token=NULL_ADDRESS,
        )
        safe_tx.sign(self.owner_private_key)
        safe_tx.call()
        hash, result = safe_tx.execute(self.owner_private_key)

        return (hash.hex(), result['nonce'])
```

We tried:

1. send by max 5, max 2 transfers,
2. send one by one with `safe.build_multisig_tx()`,
3. increase `safe_tx_gas`,
4. specify increased `tx_gas_price` in `execute`,

but it didn't change anything. What else can we do on our side to minimize the occurrence of this problem?

Answer (score 0):

`GS026` means `Invalid owner provided`, which indicates that the wrong signature has been provided to the transaction. It should not be related with the number of transactions in the multisend, nor with gas estimation. Are you sure that you (or your application) are the correct owner of the safes you are trying to interact with?

Thanks in advance for the precision. Best; Louis

Comment: All of these transactions are performed from a single safe wallet, which has a single owner. They are all ordered the same way, and we don't use another owner anywhere in this application (another private key) to sign transactions. The `owner_private_key` is like a constant here `safe_tx.sign(self.owner_private_key)` and there is no way for it to have a different value from this one proper one.